# Excepted minSdkVersion >= 21 but found 1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to run my program after doing some things with motion layout on Android Studio and now I'm getting this error if I run my program

`Excepted minSdkVersion >= 21 but found 1`

My minSdkVersion on my project is 27 and the target is 28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Re-build my project and then it works